# Python converting a string of KB into a string of Bytes

Tags: python, byte

I have a field on my web application that requires a KB. This is then reflected in the URL of the web app in Bytes form.

Can I convert a string of "500" KB to a string of Bytes in Python (expecting to get around "500000")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte):

> The kilobyte is a multiple of the unit byte for digital information.
> The International System of Units (SI) defines the prefix kilo as 1000
> (103); therefore one kilobyte is 1000 bytes.

You can simply cast it to an integer,multiply it by 1000, and return it to a string like this:

```
>>> size_in_kb = "500"
>>> bytes = str(int(size_in_kb) * 1000)
>>> bytes
'500000'
```

---

*Note: you can multiply it with 1024 instead of 1000, depends on your exact*
needs

Comment: i think It would be better using 1024